# How to open separate new activity with custom view buttons

Tags: java, android, button, android-custom-view

My `MainActivity` has an *Add* button which, when clicked, creates a new instance of my custom view: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3Uxe.png)

In its corner, my custom view has an Image Button that should open new activity, and every custom view on the list should open their own new activity (if there are 3 views in my main activity they should open 3 different new activities).

How can I create a new activity every time I add a custom view and then be able to open that new activity when I press the button?

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.teacherplanner;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageButton AddNewWeek= findViewById(R.id.add_week_btn);
        LinearLayout WeekWindow = findViewById(R.id.LIST_OF_WEEKS);


        AddNewWeek.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                WeekThumbnail NewWeek = new WeekThumbnail(MainActivity.this);
                WeekWindow.addView(NewWeek);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_week);

        ImageButton OpenEditing = findViewById(R.id.WEEK_SETTINGS);


        OpenEditing.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openWeekEditing();
            }
        });

    }

    public void openWeekEditing() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, WeekEditing.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

CustomView java file:

```
package com.example.teacherplanner;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.LayoutDirection;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintSet;

public class WeekThumbnail extends RelativeLayout {
    public WeekThumbnail(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public WeekThumbnail(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public WeekThumbnail(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_week, this, true);
    }
}
```

My custom view is tied to a java file and I tried putting my on click action there but it didn't work and when I put it in main activity every time I click it the app crashes.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I create a new activity every time I add a custom view and then be able to open that new activity when I press the button?

If your views should open completely different activities, then you should create three different Activities which will show appropriate content for specified view. But If the Activities should have the same look but only data differs between them, then you should have single Activity and upon creation pass to it data using intent extras mechanism. For exampl:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, WeekEditing.class);
intent.putExtra("key", value);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

value is the data different for each view, and in your activity you can access this data in onCreate using:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("key");
}
```

I am not sure what can cause your application to crash, for more details on working with activities, look here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/intro-activities